# why my circular slider view is not working on UIImageView in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

i am using circualr slider view which is type of `UIView`. and i am trying to set it on `UIImageView` like this::

```
[self.imageview addsubview:sliderview];
```

if i am write this line in my code. then slider view is not working.

if i add it on main view Like this:::

```
[self.view addsubview:sliderview];
```

Then it is working exactly.

Here we have two options either we can set slider on `UIImageView` or we can set the background image of slider view.but both options is not working for me.

Anyone can please suggest me for this..

Comment: check this self.imageview frame must be biger then sliderview frame and make sure self.imageview UserInteraction enable

Comment: Not working any other solution please????

Comment: can you share some portion of your code

Comment: i am adding slider view programmatically in my view controller class.
 sliderView = [[CircularSliderView alloc] initWithMinValue:0 maxValue:100 initialValue:0];
    sliderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    sliderView.frame=CGRectMake(self.iv_meter.frame.origin.x,self.iv_meter.frame.origin.y, self.iv_meter.frame.size.width, self.iv_meter.frame.size.height);
   [self.view addSubview:sliderView];

Comment: and have circular slider  seperate class which is inherit from uiview. through object m  calling that class methods.

as u can see  CircularSliderView

Comment: As jignesh Vadadoriya suggested, are you sure you added: `[self.imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`? You can see your slider in both cases right?

Comment: yeah i have added it already but its not working.